# IEqualityComparer and weird results

Tags: c#, .net, arcobjects, iequalitycomparer

Take a look at this class:

```
public class MemorialPoint:IMemorialPoint,IEqualityComparer<MemorialPoint>
{
    private string _PointName;
    private IPoint _PointLocation;
    private MemorialPointType _PointType;

    private DateTime _PointStartTime;
    private DateTime _PointFinishTime;

    private string _NeighborName;

    private double _Rms;
    private double _PointPdop;
    private double _PointHdop;
    private double _PointVdop;

    // getters and setters omitted

    public bool Equals(MemorialPoint x, MemorialPoint y)
    {
        if (x.PointName == y.PointName)
            return true;
        else if (x.PointName == y.PointName && x.PointLocation.X == y.PointLocation.X && x.PointLocation.Y == y.PointLocation.Y)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MemorialPoint obj)
    {
        return (obj.PointLocation.X.ToString() + obj.PointLocation.Y.ToString() + obj.PointName).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I also have a Vector class, which is merely two points and some other atributes. I don't want to have equal points in my Vector, so I came up with this method:

```
public void RecalculateVector(IMemorialPoint fromPoint, IMemorialPoint toPoint, int partIndex)
        {
            if (fromPoint.Equals(toPoint))
                throw new ArgumentException(Messages.VectorWithEqualPoints);

            this.FromPoint = FromPoint;
            this.ToPoint = ToPoint;
            this.PartIndex = partIndex;

            // the constructDifference method has a weird way of working:
            // difference of Point1 and Point 2, so point2 > point1 is the direction
            IVector3D vector = new Vector3DClass();
            vector.ConstructDifference(toPoint.PointLocation, fromPoint.PointLocation);

            this.Azimuth = MathUtilities.RadiansToDegrees(vector.Azimuth);

            IPointCollection pointCollection = new PolylineClass();
            pointCollection.AddPoint(fromPoint.PointLocation, ref _missing, ref _missing);
            pointCollection.AddPoint(toPoint.PointLocation, ref _missing, ref _missing);

            this._ResultingPolyline = pointCollection as IPolyline;
        }
```

And this unit test, which should give me an exception:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException), Messages.VectorWithEqualPoints)]
    public void TestMemoriaVector_EqualPoints()
    {
        IPoint p1 = PointPolygonBuilder.BuildPoint(0, 0);
        IPoint p2 = PointPolygonBuilder.BuildPoint(0, 0);

        IMemorialPoint mPoint1 = new MemorialPoint("teste1", p1);
        IMemorialPoint mPoint2 = new MemorialPoint("teste1", p2);

        Console.WriteLine(mPoint1.GetHashCode().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(mPoint2.GetHashCode().ToString());

        vector = new MemorialVector(mPoint1, mPoint1, 0);
    }
```

When i use the same point, that is, mPoint1, as in the code the exception is thrown. When I use mPoint2, even their name and coordinates being the same, the exception is not thrown. I checked their hash codes, and they are in fact different. Based on the code I created in GetHashCode, I tought these two point would have the same hashcode.

Can someone explain to me why this is not working as I tought it would? I'm not sure I explained this well, but.. I appreciate the help :D

George

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` within the type it's trying to compare - which is very odd. You should almost certainly just be implementing `IEquatable<T>` and overriding `Equals(object)` instead. That would definitely make your unit test work.

The difference between `IEquatable<T>` and `IEqualityComparer<T>` is that the former is implemented by a class to say, "I can compare *myself* with another instance of the same type." (It doesn't *have* to be the same type, but it usually is.) This is appropriate if there's a natural comparison - for example, the comparison chosen by `string` is ordinal equality - it's got to be exactly the same sequence of `char` values.

Now `IEqualityComparer<T>` is different - it can compare any two instances of a type. There can be multiple different implementations of this for a given type, so it doesn't matter whether or not a particular comparison is "the natural one" - it's just got to be the right one for your job. So for example, you could have a `Shape` class, and different equality comparers to compare shapes by colour, area or something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. That its not on the documentation. As you are saying, I could implemente IEqualityComparer<MemorialPoint>,IEqualityComparer<OtherMemorialPoint>,IEqualityComparer<OtherClass> if that was the objective.

Thanks

Comment: @George: One thing worth noting is that equality comparers are rarely meant to do anything *other* than compare other values. That should usually be their sole responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `Object.Equals` as well.

Add this to your implementation:

```
// In MemorialPoint:
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType()) 
         return false;

    MemorialPoint y = obj as MemorialPoint;

    if (this.PointName == y.PointName)
        return true;
    else if (this.PointName == y.PointName && this.PointLocation.X == y.PointLocation.X && this.PointLocation.Y == y.PointLocation.Y)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I'd then rework your other implementation to use the first, plus add the appropriate null checks.

```
public bool Equals(MemorialPoint x, MemorialPoint y)
{
    if (x == null)
        return (y == null);
    return x.Equals(y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to rethink your concept of "equality", since it's not currently meeting .NET [framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx).

If at all possible, I recommend a re-design with a Repository of memorial point objects (possibly keyed by name), so that simple reference equality can be used.

Comment: Hello Stephen. I will check that out. Thanks for pointing that out for me.

Answer (score 1):

You've put an arcobjects tag on this, so I just thought I'd mention [IRelationalOperator.Equals](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Equals_Method/002m00000343000000/).  I've never tested to see if this method honors the cluster tolerance of the geometries' spatial references.  This can be adjusted using [ISpatialReferenceTolerance.XYTolerance](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/XYTolerance_Property/002m000003r1000000/).

Comment: Hello Kirk! Nice to see you here.

I managed to do this with IEquatable<T>. My class is a wrapper for IPoint with other properties, such as name, gps precision, etc.

I will give IRelationalOperator.Equals a try, after all its much better to let AO handle this.

George